# what is the use of ?? in c#

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

I know `?` checks for null when placed before a `.` member access and `?:` for conditional statements. Although, I think `??` checks for null as well but I'm not very sure

I can't find useful information about `??` on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/

> PS. Actually I didn't look well at the MSDN reference very well. I've just seen its definition now.
>
> I though of closing this post before but I won't for the sake of anyone who wouldn't think of referring to `??` as `double question marks`in their question

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator

Answer (score 2):

that operator is sugarSyntax for operations with nullable operands

The ?? operator returns the left-hand operand if it is not null, or else it returns the right operand.

```
int? counter = null;

int backup = counter ?? 0;
```

in this case ***backup*** will be assigned with ***counter*** value **IF** ***counter*** is different to null, for something **ELSE** then ***backup*** will be assigned with **0**

note that I bold the keywords **IF-ELSE** which make us infer that ?? operand can be replaced by simple old-school if else conditionals.